# Laravel 7: How to use in data seeder array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to make distinct inserts using a custom array using database seeder?

Using the following code:

```php
$categories = ['Hardware', 'Software', 'Planning', 'Tools'];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            App\Category::insert([
                'name' => $category,
                'slug' => Str::slug($category),
            ]);
        }
```

It doesn't work without a factory for a category that is the problem matter if I use `insert` or `create`.

It gives this error

```php
Unable to locate factory for [App\Category].

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:273
    269|      */
    270|     protected function getRawAttributes(array $attributes = [])
    271|     {
    272|         if (! isset($this->definitions[$this->class])) {
  > 273|             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unable to locate factory for [{$this->class}].");
    274|         }
    275| 
    276|         $definition = call_user_func(
    277|             $this->definitions[$this->class],
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to add `key` and `value` same as the `column name` ex: `['name' => 'Hardware']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [insert](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#inserts) witch take an array as parameter:

```
public function run()
    {
        $inputs[] = ['name'=> 'Hardware'];
        $inputs[] = ['name'=> 'Software'];
        $inputs[] = ['name'=> 'Planning'];
        $inputs[] = ['name'=> 'Tools'];

        App\Category::insert($inputs);
       
    }
```

or you can do it in another way:

```
  public function run()
    {
     $inputsNames = ['Hardware', 'Software', 'Planning', 'Tools'];
     foreach($inputsNames  as $categoryName)
       {
          $inputs[]=['name'=>$categoryName];
       }    
      App\Category::insert($inputs);   
     }
```

Comment: The problem is that without a factory it will throw an error look at my updated post

Comment: Doesn't work without a factory. But can't finbd a real solution in the docs.

Comment: update method do work without factory, anyway please share your seeder code

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of data in the run method of you seeder file

```
public function run()
{
    $categories = [
        ['name' => 'Music'],
        ['name' => 'Gaming'],
        ['name' => 'Entertainment'],
        ['name' => 'Non-Profit & Activism'],
        ['name' => 'Other'],
    ];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        Category::create($category);
    }
}
```

You are pushing all data into the Model, so you need to set fillable or guarded in the Model.

```
class Category extends Model
{
      protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: I didn't explain my problem clearly enough because I didn't understand the error i was getting, My problem was that I used facker to generate a category id in post factory. something like this ```php   'category_id' => factory(Category::class)->create()->id, ``` as you can see my post factory depend on a category factory.